# How to hide following part if age and cost not have any value?

Tags: ee2, tags, entry, html

[image]

i am using following code for display about section i want to hide above section from left navigation when age and cost does not have any value please guide me thank you

```
 <div class="filter-attribute">
  <h3>Filter By</h3>
</div>
<div class="attirbute-name">
  <h2>Age</h2>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="science_projects" search:age="1-20|21-40|41-60|61-80|81-100" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
  {if age != "Select Age Range"}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">{age}</a></li>
  </ul>
  {/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries} </div>
<div class="attirbute-name">
  <h2>Cost</h2>
  {exp:channel:entries channel="science_projects" search:cost="Low|Medium|High" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
  {if cost != "Select Cost Option"}
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">{cost}</a></li>
  </ul>
  {/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries} </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="science_projects" search:age="1-20|21-40|41-60|61-80|81-100" limit="3" dynamic="off" sort="desc"}
{if age != "Select Age Range"}
  {if count == "1"}
    <div class="filter-attribute">
    <h3>Filter By</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="attirbute-name">
    <h2>Age</h2>
  {/if}
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">{age}</a></li>
    </ul>
  {if count == total_results}
    </div>
  {/if}
{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```